# Will my comic reader app violate Comixology patent?

Tags: patentability, computer-graphics, ios, us20100318895

I am developing an app for iOS devices which has almost the same guided view type reader for comic panels. There are a lot of posts on the web about fights between Marvel and Comixology regarding the patent of this viewer. I was wondering if my reader app can violate the patent guidelines. Secondly, if it does, still in wiki the technology has been written as "patent-pending"and if I can publish my app right now, will It still be an offensive app?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents!. You may have reached the site from a button on google patents but that did not insert the patent document number you are referring to into your posted question. Please edit your post with the patent number in question.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your comment. I am a developer and have no idea how this patent thing works. I have almost finished my app and while I was getting ready to upload, I came across a post on wiki regarding the patent filing of comixology. It really was frustrating. So I posted the question here. I googled a lot to find patent number as you have asked but couldn't find it. Can you please suggest any URL where I can find this patent number?

Comment: A good way to search patent information is at http://www.google.com/patents. There is also a google advanced patent search (google it). I put comics in the primary search box and the name of the Comixology CEO in the inventor box. The search found Systems, Methods, and Media for Presenting Panel-Based Electronic Documents US20100318895

Comment: @Ranadhir - I'm curious, did you release your app? were you approached by Comixology or other to take it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Systems, Methods, and Media for Presenting Panel-Based Electronic Documents
US 20100318895](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100318895) is an application, *not* yet an issued patent. Some of the web articles that mention it also note that Marvel (via Disney) has an issued patent US 8301999 that covers similar territory.

The entire history of the prosecution of any recent patent or application can be seen at USPTO Public PAIR. The current status of the Comixology application seen there is:

[image]

It has had a long history now of many rejections and corresponding claim amendments and arguments. Anyone can follow the progress there. Unless and until a patent is granted its owner has no right to stop anyone. Of course, once issued, the fact that something is already shipping isn't relevant to whether or not it infringes.